# cant find any site with themes for sugar

Tags: sugarcrm

its odd I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find a site with themes for sugarcrm community edition. like nothing for the new version at all.
if you know of any site please do let me know.
Thank you much in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can find a theme here on SugarOutfitters: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/google-style-sugartheme

Themes can be hard to find because they can be so difficult to make. This one pulls it off and adds a couple of additional productivity features.

Comment: thanks @egg yeah thats an okay theme and its 400 dollars seems like a lot for a theme.I can create one my self I thought finding one would be cheaper but at that price I would rather restyle the default theme myself

Comment: Fair enough. I'd argue spending your time creating a theme yourself will end up costing many times over that. But if that is time you have available anyway then definitely go that route. BTW - that theme is one of our more popular listings. Would love to see more themes. People always want it.

Comment: I created one already but I dont like it now its finished...so i thought i d find another one for 50 - 100 bucks and buy it and issue resolved. and yes there are no themes online at all, so im sure if you develop more themes they will sell for sure good luck with that.

Comment: sugaroutfitters site is very nice. I love the design - well done!

Comment: Thanks @fogsy! If you make one that you like please feel free to list it on our site. We'd love to see more themes out there for everyone to use.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple here as well: http://www.sugarforge.org/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=335